# What is the added value of the new 'insertIgnoreUsing' from Laravel 10.43

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently looking at the new methods in Laravel 10.43. I'm wondering how to use the insertIgnore method correctly. The old insertIgnore method was easy to understand. But here I'm wondering what exactly it does and how to use it for a bulk insert? The example is not really self-explanatory, in my opinion.

```php
$result = $builder->from('table1')->insertOrIgnoreUsing(
    ['foo'],
    function (Builder $query) {
        $query->select(['bar'])->from('table2')->where('foreign_id', '=', 5);
    }
);
```

```
insert ignore into `table1` (`foo`) select `bar` from `table2` where `foreign_id` = ?'
```

**Source:** https://laravel-news.com/laravel-10-43-0#content-new-eloquent-insertorignoreusing-method

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski I edit my question. I hope it is easier to understand what my problem is. Dzienki

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inserting entries into table1 using entries from table2.

Now imagine you have a constraint like a unicity (id, emails, composite primary key...) on table1.

If you run the same code twice it will trigger an error since, when inserting the second time, the unicity constraint will stop you.

Now, using `insertOrIgnoreUsing` will simply ignore the entries that will trigger the error and continue with the insert.

If you're asking "how is this usefull ?" you are right if we are running the code twice consecutively. But filling a table from another one by running the same script after a period is like synching the tables.
It can be used for dispatching jobs, making backups or simply synching at specific time in a period.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your reply. InsertIgnore is already an older method of Laravel. Therefore I already knew this advantage. What I don't understand about the new one are the two passed parameters. Once an array and then a query. I don't understand why and what the query is supposed to do?

Comment: @MartinTTS it might be easier to check the doc for `insertUsing` https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#insert-statements . Basically it inserts data using data from the database. faster than recovering the data then send it back to be inserted.